# Bound the value of function by integration of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, multiple-integral, discrete-calculus

Given $f(x,y) \in C^2([0,1]^2)$ (by which I mean $C^2$ in some open neighborhood), with $f_x, f_y, f_{xy} \in L^1([0,1]^2, dxdy)$ (which is sure case since they are continuous), does the following hold?
$$
\sup |f| \le \iint |f|+|f_x|+|f_y|+|f_{xy}|\, dxdy $$

I think it is safe to

1. discretise this function under the assumptions,
2. divide $f$ into positive part and negative part, and
3. consider $f-\inf f$ instead so that one could assume that $f\ge 0$.

Denote $a=f(0,0)$, $b=f(0,1)$, $c=f(1,0)$, $d=f(1,1)$, and I want to show
$$\max \{a, b, c, d\}\le \frac14 (a+b+c+d)+\frac12 (|b-a|+|c-a|+|d-b|+|d-c|)+(|d-c-b+a|),$$
which is not hard and done with absolute value inequalities.

As I move on to refine the division, I find difficulties with those coefficients. RHS reads to me as
$$\frac1{(n+1)^2} \sum f_{ij}+\sum \frac {\delta_i f_{ij}+\delta_i f_{i,j+1}}{2n}+\sum \frac {\delta_j f_{ij}+\delta_j f_{i+1,j}}{2n}+\sum \Delta f_{ij},$$
where $i,j \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}, f_{ij}=f(i,j)$, $\delta_i f_{ij}=|f_{i+1,j}-f_{ij}|$,$\Delta f_{ij}=|f_{i+1, j+1}-f_{i+1,j}-f_{i,j+1}+f_{ij}|$.

I still want to show that $\max \{f_{ij}\}$ is less than the above expression. Or maybe some other simpler solution.

Comment: If $f$ is radial, then $f_{xy} = f_{xx} = f_{yy}$ and this is true and follows from the continuous Sobolev's embedding $W^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^2) ⊂  L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I suspect it is false in the general case, but I have no counterexample right now ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I guess an embedding thm only provides something like $\mathrm{norm}_1\le c\cdot\mathrm{norm}_2$?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the claim is wrong considering an indicator function of a tiny square $[0,r]^2$ and some smooth approximations of it.